# ASP.NET MVC: What's the best way to validate the expiry/legitimate of querysting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have a payment successful page where we read the query string ?paid=yes.

If paid=yes then we show the payment sucessfull message etc. Otherwise payment failed.

What's the best way to:

1. Validate ?paid=yes query string is valid? In other words, how can we stop people from manually manipulating query string ?
2. Set query string expiry time or set attempt (max 1)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As usual: never trust user input. The only difference between a request with `?paid=yes` or not in the querystring would be the message you show. You have to find a different way to validate the payment by communicating with the payment provider directly to check the result.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you cant validate a payment in a query, I would instead give the client a ticket, so now the query would be `?ticket=UUID`, where uuid can be generated with GUID class `Giud.NewGuid()`.

now in the database of your server you should create the ticket too and a boolean field indicating if the payment is done.